# What is the equivalent of Unity's Transform.Forward in Stride

Tags: transformation, stride

To get the forward direction in Unity, I use `Transform.Forward`. How do I do this in Stride?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [official documentation](https://doc.stride3d.net/4.0/en/Manual/stride-for-unity-developers/index.html#transform-directions), Stride3D's equivalent to Unity's `mygameobject.transform.forward` is:

`myentity.Transform.WorldMatrix.Forward`